# Angular2: One or more of providers for .. were not defined: [?]

Tags: angular

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: One or more of providers for "AddressPage" were
>   not defined: [?].

My Code is sound I think:

```
@Injectable()

export class NavService { .. }

import {NavService} from '../../../providers/services/nav-service/nav-service';
@Component({
    templateUrl:    'build/pages/transaction/address/address.html',
    providers:      [NavService]
})

export class AddressPage { .. }
```

Yet I am seeing this error, what the heck does it mean? In another component that looks similar I do not have trouble importing the service. Also my tests for the service run fine. I am debugging this for hours now, any help is appreciated.

**Update**

### Bootstrap

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [

    GoalService, 

    provide(TranslateLoader, {
        useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
    }), TranslateService,

    provide(AuthHttp, {
        useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp (
                new AuthConfig(), 
                http
            )
        },
        deps: [Http]
    }), AuthService,

    NavService
])
```

### Debugging done

I exchanged the source code of my two component files (non-working and working) and still receive the `[?] Provider not defined` error. So the problem must be outside the files somewhere.

This is the function throwing the error in Angular2 source:

```
@@ -124,6 +125,10 @@ export class CompileMetadataResolver {
                verifyNonBlankProviders(directiveType, dirMeta.viewProviders, 'viewProviders'));
          }
          moduleUrl = componentModuleUrl(this._reflector, directiveType, cmpMeta);
 +        if (cmpMeta.precompile) {
 +          precompileTypes = flattenArray(cmpMeta.precompile)
 +                                .map((cmp) => this.getTypeMetadata(cmp, staticTypeModuleUrl(cmp)));
 +        }
        }

        var providers: any[] /** TODO #9100 */ = [];
```

### Root Cause

Ok - this was the problem: I pushed via navController to the next page inside of my service, but "the next page" needs that very service as dependency/provider, which is not possible because it is a cyclic dependency. I need a clean solution for this - do we have a best-practice yet?

### Possible Solution?

Cast the string "MyNextPage" to type "MyNextPage" ? I tried with

```
console.log ("Casted", <AddressPage>nextPageString)
```

..but it fails to cast to a function.

Comment: With this, it is hard to identify prbm. Show us bootstrap function, almost required code from service n component.

Comment: OK updated. Strange thing is it works in other component.

Comment: I also experience this, and it is because of `cyclic dependency`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I really understand your question, but maybe you try to inject NavService in MyApp module, but NavService provided only in component not in module.

Example:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [NavService],
})
export class AddressPageModule{
}
```

And import module with provided service where u need:

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [AddressPageModule]
 })
 export class MyAppModule{
 }
```

Comment: The question was asked 6 years ago, unsure if it is even relevant anymore.